# How to deploy an iPhone app just have a link to download app without any manual configurations (automated)

Tags: ios, app-store

I would like to public my iOS App without submit to app store, so every people can download my app by just only access link on the browser. I knew some ways to do that:

- adhoc but thats limited to 100 device and required to configure UDID

Is there any way to provide a link to download that should we use enterprise ?

Comment: Why are you trying to get around the official app store?  to save $99 USD? You could always use the "Jailbroken" app store, [Cydia](https://cydia.saurik.com), but that requires the phones to be jailbroken.

Comment: No I don't want to save the $99 USD, but I want all my users more easy they just access to download app by link (URL)